# Removing a prior sample while using Welford's method for computing single pass variance

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I'm successfully using Welford's method to compute running variance and standard deviation as described many times on Stack Overflow and [John D Cook's excellent blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/).

However in the stream of samples, sometimes I encounter a "rollback", or "remove sample" order, meaning that a previous sample is no longer valid and should be removed from the calculation.  I know the value of the sample to remove and when it was processed.  But I'm using Welford because I can not go back do another pass over all the data.

Is there an algorithm to successfully adjust my running variance to remove or negate a specific previously processed sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the forward formulas

```
Mk = Mk-1 + (xk – Mk-1) / k
Sk = Sk-1 + (xk – Mk-1) * (xk – Mk),
```

it's possible to solve for `Mk-1` as a function of `Mk` and `xk` and `k`:

```
Mk-1 = Mk - (xk - Mk) / (k - 1).
```

Then we can derive `Sk-1` straightforwardly from `Sk` and the rest:

```
Sk-1 = Sk - (xk – Mk-1) * (xk – Mk).
```

It's not necessary that `xk` be the last sample here; since `Mk` and `Sk` theoretically do not depend on the order of the input, we can pretend that the sample to be removed was the last to be added.

I have no idea if this is stable.

Comment: Yes thank you, that formula appears to do what I needed based on testing in Excel.